# Oracle Table to SAS Dataset

Tags: linux, oracle, sas

I am facing a problem in converting a large Oracle table to a SAS dataset. I did this earlier and the method worked. However, this time, it is giving me the following error messages.

```
SAS code:

option compress = yes;
libname sasdata ".";
libname myora oracle user=scott password=tiger path=XYZDATA ;
data sasdata.expt_tabl;
   set myora.expt_tabl;
run;

Log file:

You are running SAS 9. Some SAS 8 files will be automatically converted
by the V9 engine; others are incompatible.  Please see
http://support.sas.com/rnd/migration/planning/platform/64bit.html

PROC MIGRATE will preserve current SAS file attributes and is
recommended for converting all your SAS libraries from any
SAS 8 release to SAS 9.  For details and examples, please see
http://support.sas.com/rnd/migration/index.html


This message is contained in the SAS news file, and is presented upon
initialization.  Edit the file "news" in the "misc/base" directory to
display site-specific news and information in the program log.
The command line option "-nonews" will prevent this display.




NOTE: SAS initialization used:
      real time           1.63 seconds
      cpu time            0.03 seconds

1          option compress = yes;
2          libname sasdata ".";
NOTE: Libref SASDATA was successfully assigned as follows:
      Engine:        V9
      Physical Name: /******/dibyendu
3          libname myora oracle user=scott password=XXXXXXXXXX path=XYZDATA ;
NOTE: Libref MYORA was successfully assigned as follows:
      Engine:        ORACLE
      Physical Name: XYZDATA
4          data sasdata.expt_tabl;
5             set myora.expt_tabl;
6          run;

NOTE: There were 6422133 observations read from the data set MYORA.EXPT_TABL.DATA.
ERROR: Expecting page 1, got page -1 instead.
ERROR: Page validation error while reading SASDATA.EXPT_TABL.DATA.
ERROR: Expecting page 1, got page -1 instead.
ERROR: Page validation error while reading SASDATA.EXPT_TABL.DATA.
ERROR: File SASDATA.EXPT_TABL.DATA is damaged. I/O processing did not complete.
NOTE: The data set SASDATA.EXPT_TABL.DATA has 6422133 observations and 49 variables.
ERROR: Expecting page 1, got page -1 instead.
ERROR: Page validation error while reading SASDATA.EXPT_TABL.DATA
ERROR: Expecting page 1, got page -1 instead.
ERROR: Page validation error while reading SASDATA.EXPT_TABL.DATA.
ERROR: Expecting page 1, got page -1 instead.
2                                                          The SAS System                                21:40 Monday, April 1, 2013

ERROR: Page validation error while reading SASDATA.EXPT_TABL.DATA.
ERROR: Expecting page 1, got page -1 instead.
ERROR: Page validation error while reading SASDATA.EXPT_TABL.DATA.
NOTE: Compressing data set SASDATA.EXPT_TABL.DATA decreased size by 78.88 percent.
      Compressed is 37681 pages; un-compressed would require 178393 pages.
ERROR: File SASDATA.EXPT_TABL.DATA is damaged. I/O processing did not complete.
NOTE: SAS set option OBS=0 and will continue to check statements. This might cause NOTE: No observations in data set.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           8:55.98
      cpu time            1:39.33


7

ERROR: Errors printed on pages 1,2.

NOTE: SAS Institute Inc., SAS Campus Drive, Cary, NC USA 27513-2414
NOTE: The SAS System used:
      real time           8:58.67
      cpu time            1:39.40
```

This is running on a RH Linux Server.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Thanks and regards,

Comment: That sounds like potentially a session-specific error.  Have you tried rerunning the process?  Perhaps rebooting the server (or at least re-logging in)?

Comment: I tried to run it many times. It gives the same error messages!!

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a space issue on your server.  How large is the file system in your default directory (from your `libname sasdata '.';` statement)?  Use the data set option `obs=1` on your Oracle table reference to create a new SAS dataset with one row and inspect the variables.

```
data sasdata.dummy_test;
     set myora.expt_tabl(obs=1);
run;
```

Perhaps there are extremely large VARCHAR or BLOB columns that are consuming too much space.  Remember that SAS does not have a VARCHAR type.

Comment: I was experimenting a bit by increasing the number of records gradually. It was working fine initially, but when I tried with 1000000 records, it started giving trouble.

Comment: That seems to confirm that it is a problem with the file system.  If you have a friendly system administrator for your Linux box, ask for some help.  Some Linux file systems have a maximum file size of 2 GB; I bet that is the limit you are exceeding.  In other words, this is not a SAS problem (rather not really).

Comment: I have created larger than 2G datasets earlier. I find datasets of size 2.7G, 2.3G and 2.1G created in the same manner. They reside in the same location and did not give me any trouble.

Comment: I don't have any BLOBs or CLOBs in the Oracle table. The interesting part is that I do not get any error message in the log when I include >= 1000000 records. I get the errors when I try to run proc freq etc.

Comment: Well then I'm confused; the error message you showed was regarding creating a new SAS dataset and now you say you're using proc freq?  This might better be resolved by opening a track with SAS tech support.  I'm sure they will help you more directly.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to create a SAS dataset for subsequent analysis. The "creation" part does not show the error(s) sometimes [sometime it DOES!!], but the subsequent analysis steps always show the error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Though I am not totally sure, I believe the main issue was that I was initially trying to create/write the dataset in a directory, which was restricted in some (?) sense. This was indirectly causing trouble, since the dataset created was defective. When I created it elsewhere, it was okay.

Thanks and regards,
Dibyendu